# Почему конструктор не принимает значение?

Tags: javascript

```
function Dictionary(startValues){
    this.values = startValues || {}; 
};
Dictionary.prototype.set = function(key, value){
    this.value[key] = value;
};
Dictionary.prototype.get = function(key){
    return this.value[key];
};
var users = new Dictionary({John: 'admin'});
var role = users.get('John');
users.set('Mike', 'manager');
```

Написал конструктор но выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'John' of undefined.
Как подправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this.value**s**[key]

ну и по стилю рекомендация - переименуйте методы set/get в setRole/getRole